# Idiomatic way of requiring HTTP Basic Auth in Go?

Tags: go

**Situation:**

I'm building a REST API using Gorilla's mux as the router.

I'm wondering how I can protect specific routes with simple HTTP Basic Auth. I don't have a need to read the credentials from a file or any external source, I really just want to protect selected routes by a hard coded HTTP Basic Auth username and password.

**Question:**

What is the idiomatic way of doing so in Go? Does Gorilla offer anything to make it more easy? If you could provide a few lines of code, that would be just wonderful.

Comment: You're gonna want to make a middleware that checks the `Authorization` header. https://github.com/gorilla/mux/pull/36

Answer (score 53):

Combining a couple of answers into an easy copy/paste:

```
// BasicAuth wraps a handler requiring HTTP basic auth for it using the given
// username and password and the specified realm, which shouldn't contain quotes.
//
// Most web browser display a dialog with something like:
//
//    The website says: "<realm>"
//
// Which is really stupid so you may want to set the realm to a message rather than
// an actual realm.
func BasicAuth(handler http.HandlerFunc, username, password, realm string) http.HandlerFunc {

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        user, pass, ok := r.BasicAuth()

        if !ok || subtle.ConstantTimeCompare([]byte(user), []byte(username)) != 1 || subtle.ConstantTimeCompare([]byte(pass), []byte(password)) != 1 {
            w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="`+realm+`"`)
            w.WriteHeader(401)
            w.Write([]byte("Unauthorised.\n"))
            return
        }

        handler(w, r)
    }
}

...

http.HandleFunc("/", BasicAuth(handleIndex, "admin", "123456", "Please enter your username and password for this site"))
```

Note that `subtle.ConstantTimeCompare()` still depends on the length, so it is probably possible for attackers to work out the length of the username and password if you do it like this. To get around that you could hash them or add a fixed delay.

Comment: This is the only correct answer to the question of idiom, and the only sensibly secure answer.

Comment: What added benefits are there for using ConstantTimeCompare if the username/password check is done on the server side? I'm genuinely curious because I use a similar method to this one but with basic comparisons. I haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: If you don't use `ConstantTimeCompare()` people could work out how long the operation took. From that they can work out how much of the password matches and try all letters until the first letter of the password matches, then the second and so on. If you hash the passwords before comparison (which you really should - passwords shouldn't be stored in plain text) then it isn't so much of an issue but is probably still a good idea anyway. You'll never notice any issues if you don't do it but it is a potential security vulnerability.

Comment: Makes sense. I appreciate the insight. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure that's nonsense, at least for a public internet facing app and basic authentication.... try timing the difference between a 3 and a 4 digit password with all of the latency between systems. A single comparison in assembler is 1-3 clock cycles depending on register or memory compare... and CPU/RAM cache. Bubble that code up through several layers of C and/or native go with network latency and ... you gotta show proof. Not to mention that in the above example it's a plaintext compare. OH and let's also say that the hacker does not know if there is a DB or cache.

Comment: @Richard "I can't think how this could ever happen so it probably can't." is exactly the sort of thinking that leads to security flaws. [Timing attacks can be done over a network](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/183826/143186). In this case I think it would *probably* not be possible, but I expect that is what the OpenSSH developers thought too.

Comment: nit: instead of the w.WriteHeader + w.Write calls with the 401 magic number, I suggest just using `http.Error(w, "Unauthorized", http.StatusUnauthorized)`

Answer (score 25):

Check req.BasicAuth()
https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.BasicAuth

You can check this in your handler or wrap your handler like so:

```
func auth(fn http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user, pass, _ := r.BasicAuth()
    if !check(user, pass) {
       http.Error(w, "Unauthorized.", 401)
       return
    }
    fn(w, r)
  }
}
```

Where

```
check(u, p string) bool
```

is a function you will have to write yourself based on how you are storing credentials. Now you can use:

```
auth(originalHandler)
```

Wherever you were passing originalHandler before.

[edit: It's worth adding that your check function should be resistant to side channel attacks like timing attacks. Also stored passwords should be hashed with a cryptographically random salt. Also you should probably use OAuth instead and let an established identity provider worry about password security for you.]

Comment: `http.Error(w, "Unauthorized.", http.StatusUnauthorized)`

Comment: I second Matt Williamson's suggestion to use the more semantic statuscode constant. Also add `w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"MY REALM\"")` before `http.Error()` to make the browser prompt for the password.

Answer (score 20):

As of 2016, I would suggest to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39591234/1643939). In any case, wrap your HTTP basic auth in SSL to avoid sending username and password as plain text.

---

Just wrap your handler in another handler and use issue WWW-Authorization header on the incoming request.

Example ([full version](http://play.golang.org/p/IbzYPFwsoo)):

```
func checkAuth(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) bool {
    s := strings.SplitN(r.Header.Get("Authorization"), " ", 2)
    if len(s) != 2 { return false }

    b, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s[1])
    if err != nil { return false }

    pair := strings.SplitN(string(b), ":", 2)
    if len(pair) != 2 { return false }

    return pair[0] == "user" && pair[1] == "pass"
}

yourRouter.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if checkAuth(w, r) {
        yourOriginalHandler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="MY REALM"`)
    w.WriteHeader(401)
    w.Write([]byte("401 Unauthorized\n"))
})
```

Unfortunately, the std. library only offers [client basic auth](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.SetBasicAuth) and therefore you have to
do it yourself or use a library, for example [this one](https://github.com/abbot/go-http-auth/).

Comment: Based on @Romoku's comment and @nemo's checkAuth function, I've made a more complete example that allows you to wrap any `http.HandlerFunc` with a piece of middleware that implements HTTP Basic Auth. Take a look here: https://gist.github.com/elithrar/9146306

Comment: need :

 import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "strings")

Comment: Your example is vulnerable to timings attacks. Copypasters should use `crypto/subtle` when verifying username and password.

Answer (score 5):

The `net/http` request type has helper functions for doing this (tested on go 1.7). A simpler version of nemo's answer would look like such:

```
func basicAuthHandler(user, pass, realm string, next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if checkBasicAuth(r, user, pass) {
            next(w, r)
            return
        }

        w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", fmt.Sprintf(`Basic realm="%s"`, realm))
        w.WriteHeader(401)
        w.Write([]byte("401 Unauthorized\n"))
    }
}

func checkBasicAuth(r *http.Request, user, pass string) bool {
    u, p, ok := r.BasicAuth()
    if !ok {
        return false
    }
    return u == user && p == pass
}
```

then simply create your handler with business logic and pass it as the `next` argument in `basicAuthHandler` to create a new "wrapped" handlerFunc.

Comment: This is also the cleanest (most readable) least pretentious version of the code.

Answer (score 2):

[go-http-auth](https://github.com/abbot/go-http-auth) will do it for you. It will fit right in if you're using `net/http`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you provide very basic example which illustrates this?

Comment: I don't recommend this package, the documentation is very incomplete

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm late to the party here. I just happened to be revisiting HTTP Basic Authentication. After going through all the answers here I actually settled on a variation of Timmmm's solution. I even took it the step farther and added the hashing as per his suggestion to improve security. Figured I might as well share my variation of the code.

```
userhash := hasher("admin")
passhash := hasher("$CrazyUnforgettablePassword?")
realm := "Please enter username and password"

http.HandleFunc("/", authHandler(indexHandler, userhash, passhash, realm))

// Above code should obviously be in main() along with the http listener, etc.

// hasher uses package "crypto/sha256"
func hasher(s string) []byte {
    val := sha256.Sum256([]byte(s))
    return val[:]
}

func authHandler(handler http.HandlerFunc, userhash, passhash []byte, realm string) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        user, pass, ok := r.BasicAuth()
        if !ok || subtle.ConstantTimeCompare(hasher(user),
            userhash) != 1 || subtle.ConstantTimeCompare(hasher(pass), passhash) != 1 {
            w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="`+realm+`"`)
            http.Error(w, "Unauthorized.", http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }
        handler(w, r)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use MD5 for password hashing. Use something like [PBKDF2](https://gowalker.org/golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2).

Comment: pbkdf2 isn't part of the standard library. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How about a Sha256 Sum? If not, could you elaborate on why it would be a bad idea? I could use a more constructive answer than "don't use it'.

Comment: the `x` repository for PBKDF2 which I linked is official but 'experimental', meaning that it is not yet part of the standard library because the API might change. It is still possible to use and almost certainly better than using MD5. An alternative would be to use blowfish or SHA256 with a randomly generated salt.

Comment: Sha256 doesn't take a Salt from what I see in the standard crypto/sha256 package.

Comment: Salting is not a process that requires special functionality, it is the process of adding additional bytes to the bytes you want to hash. There are certain things you need to watch out for. For example, for Merkle-Damgård (MD) hash functions you must not append the salt bytes since then you could precompute all MD rounds until the last one and compute the salt independently. More info [here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). In essence, if you are not sure, use something that already does what you want (bcrypt, PBKDF2).

Comment: I think you are assuming the hackers would be able to access the hashed data. This hashing is happening on the server side out of view. The general idea of using hashing, according to Timmmm, was to accompany the subtle time compare to help thwart the ability to figure out how much of the password matches based on how long the operation took. I think we've accomplished that already. So I'm content with the answer as it stands. Especially considering it's probably the most secure answer in this thread. Even yours doesn't use any hashing or encryption.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139898/discussion-between-lee8oi-and-nemo).